# localhost - Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes?

Tags: javascript, axios

I have the following function:

```
this.Locations = axios.get('localhost:8081/fetchData?table=locations').then((res) => {                                         
  return res
})
```

and in my app.js I have an endpoint set up '/fetchData' which works fine if I just execute in the browser.

How come I am getting this error message?

```
Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

Comment: specify http or https?

Answer (score 5):

You need to specify a scheme, for example, `http://`. Change your function to:

```
this.Locations = axios.get('http://localhost:8081/fetchData?table=locations').then((res) => {                                         
  return res
})
```

Comment: @NicollasBraga Because an absolute URL must start with a scheme name. If it is not defined, there is no way to determine which scheme to use. That's why the request is not allowed. Actually, `localhost:8081` isn't even a valid URL. Yes, If we type it in the browser bar, the browser will fix it by adding a `http://` in front of it, but it is done just for the user convenience